# Jump to active accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a page with a big accordion, when the user click on next step i refresh the page and i set active the next accordion, but the user for see the last accordion is obliged to scroll down with the mouse.

My goal is to set the active accordion automatically in the window (without using animation), i tried to search an answer on the net but i had found solution only with the animation and I don' want it.

The accordion is the same that foundation framework has in his documentation, http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html , the only difference is that I have 10 panel.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code so far.

Comment: @Adam Sorry,I had edited my question

Comment: Could you please post your code ? Put anchor on each accordeon section, then when reloading the page do like `document.location.assign(document.location.href.replace(/(#.+)?$/,'#YOUR_HASHTAG_HERE'));`